# Proper tag highlighting in Vim?

Tags: html, vim, syntax-highlighting, macvim

Just getting into Vim, but can't figure out why it's not highlighting these HTML tags properly. Shouldn't the closing body and html tags be bold and red? See pic.

[image: Vim html document]

Comment: What's the output of `:filetype` and `:set filetype`?

Comment: `:filetype` = `filetype detection:ON plugin:OFF indent:OFF` and 
`:set filetype` = `filetype=php`

Answer (score 2):

Most colorschemes don't go very far beyond the generic highlight groups like `Keyword` or `String`.

My favorite colorscheme is Sorcerer but I had to customize it like that :

```
hi htmlTag            guifg=#90b0d1 gui=NONE 
hi htmlSpecialTagName guifg=#90b0d1 gui=NONE 
hi htmlTagName        guifg=#90b0d1 gui=NONE  
hi htmlEndTag         guifg=#90b0d1 gui=NONE
```

to obtain this:

[image: correct html tags highlighting in Vim]