# Proper html attribute highlighting in Vim?

Tags: html, vim, syntax-highlighting

While I was looking for proper html tag highlighting in Vim, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132877/proper-tag-highlighting-in-vim). But after looking at romainl's answer (and his screenshot) and html syntax file, I wonder how can I change color of = (equal sign) after attribute to match the color of an attribute without changing html tag's color?

Comment: Did you look at the source of Sorcerer (the theme romainl says he's using) to see how it's done there?

Comment: romainl must've customize it also because in Sorcerer ='s color is different than att's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. **Exploration**

   Here is a very useful function I've found somewhere (a long time ago, probably on the Vim Wiki) that gives you the syntax group of the word/symbol under your cursor:

   ```
   function! SynStack()
       if !exists("*synstack")
           return
       endif
       echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
   endfunc
   ```

   Just place your cursor on the item you want to inspect and type `:call SynStack()` to echo the syntax group in the command-line.

   If I place my cursor on the `=` in `<div id="example"></div>`, the output of `SynStack()` is `['htmlTag']`.

   With the cursor on `<>` I get `['htmlTag']` as well.

   With the cursor on `div` I get `['htmlTag', 'htmlTagN', 'htmlTagName']` which means that the color of `div` (`h1`, `p`…) is defined via a special syntax group called `htmlTagName` that inherits from `htmlTag`.

   Some alternative/custom syntax files may define other syntax groups with slightly varying name so my example is only valid for me. You'll have to play with `SynStack()` to get the correct syntax groups.
2. **Reflexion**

   With the info we have gathered so far, it's obvious that the tag name (`['htmlTagName']`) can be styled independtly from the rest of the tag but it doesn't seem doable to highlight the `=` differently. Because it is part of the same syntax group as `<>`, the `=` will necessarilly be highlighted the same.

   We have 2 possibilities:

   a. `<`, `=` and `>` are the same colour while `div` is different.

   b. `<`, `div`, `=` and `>` are all the same colour.

   The original theme followed path `a` which I didn't like, so I had to customize it a little (path `b`) with the few lines in my answer to the previous question:

   ```
   hi htmlTag            guifg=#90b0d1 gui=NONE 
   hi htmlSpecialTagName guifg=#90b0d1 gui=NONE 
   hi htmlTagName        guifg=#90b0d1 gui=NONE  
   hi htmlEndTag         guifg=#90b0d1 gui=NONE
   ```

   As it is, having the `=` coloured differently than `<>` is not possible. If we want to colorize the `=` we are going to edit the HTML syntax file *and* your colorscheme, cowboy style.
3. **Action**

   **The first step** is to make a local copy of the default HTMl syntax file:

   ```
   $ cp /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/html.vim ~/.vim/syntax/html.vim
   ```

   **The next step** is to edit this file. We are going to perform two changes:

   1. add the definition of the `htmlEqualSign` syntax group

      Line 44 should be (Attention! Not thoroughly tested.):

      ```
      syn match htmlEqualSign contained "="
      ```
   2. add `htmlEqualSign` to the `htmlTag` group

      Line 40 of `~/.vim/syntax/html.vim` should be changed from:

      ```
      syn region htmlTag start=+<[^/]+ end=+>+ contains=htmlTagN,htmlString,htmlArg,htmlValue,htmlTagError,htmlEvent,htmlCssDefinition,@htmlPreproc,@htmlArgCluster
      ```

      to:

      ```
      syn region htmlTag start=+<[^/]+ end=+>+ contains=htmlTagN,htmlString,htmlArg,htmlValue,htmlTagError,htmlEvent,htmlCssDefinition,@htmlPreproc,@htmlArgCluster,htmlEqualSign
      ```

   **The last step** is to edit your colorscheme so that it colorizes `=` the way you want. You do that by adding this line somewhere in your colorscheme:

   ```
   hi htmlEqualSign guifg=#00ff00
   ```

   With the color of your choice, of course.

   But I think that you want `=` to be the same color as `id` (that's not very clear from your question). For that, we are going to "link" the `htmlEqualSign` group to the one being used for attributes. Again, `:call SynStack()` is of great help: the syntax group for attributes is `htmlArg` so the line to add to your colorscheme would be:

   ```
   hi link htmlEqualSign htmlArg
   ```

Comment: I know it's an old post, but I would like to add some information to your great post. I didn't need to edit the file `html.vim`, it's easier. When we define the syntax group, we only need this line: `syn match htmlEqualSign /=/ containedin=ALL`. Finally we highlight the group.