# How can I get Vim HTML syntax highlighting to colour the whole tag?

Tags: html, vim, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

As a PhpStorm user, one of the disappointing things I come across when I try using Vim is the way it does syntax highlighting in HTML:

[image]

Vim colours just the tagname and attributes,leaving the <, / and > in a different colour. What's the point of that? I find this distracting compared to the view I get in PhpStorm:

[image]

(Ignore the different colour scheme.) I find it harder to read code with all those `<` and `>` characters. How I can modify Vim to do this?

I'm using the monokai colour scheme for Vim.

Comment: maybe you can fork monokai repo and modify open and close tags in html, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10693291/5215927

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to modify the HTML syntax itself - this can all be done by overriding the default links. `syntax/html.vim` defines *syntax groups* for the various HTML elements, and (at the end of the script) then *links* those to certain *highlight groups*, the appearance of which is determined by your *colorscheme*. If you establish a different link (in your `~/.vimrc`), this will be honored. So, to make the entire tag appear like the tag name, use this:

```
highlight link htmlTag htmlTagName
highlight link htmlEndTag htmlTagName
```

Comment: Thanks Ingo - I added these lines to the bottom of my .vimrc, but unfortunately I'm still getting the old style of highlighting, with whole tags only coloured the same when the cursor is over them.

Comment: Strange. Do you have any other plugins, e.g. for highlighting matching tags? Or do you have `'cursorline'` set? The [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin might help troubleshooting this.

Comment: Thanks - I've just tried this on my Vim on another computer, and it does the trick - must be a plugin on my other one. Marking this as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make a local copy of `syntax/html.vim` in `~/.vim/syntax/html.vim` (where the first filename is your system install dir).

Experiment with changing the hilight group of `htmlTag` and `htmlTagEnd` (near the bottom of the syntax file) to match the hilight group of `htmlTagName`.  I like the default, so I only experimented on a few files, and it didn't seem to break anything. Being the same colour, there shouldn't be anymore chevrons sticking it to your receptor cones.

Being such a simple minded test, this does likely break something somewhere, and you'll probably have to spend a few minutes with the other hilight groups to get a consistent look.

Comment: Hm, thanks Brian, I tried changing the settings "hi def link htmlTag" and "hi def link  htmlEndTag" from "Function" and "Identifier" to "htmlStatement" same as htmlTagName - this only fixes the colouring when the cursor is on that tag - I guess I need the style of unselected tags as well.

Comment: I think the behaviour I was seeing with this solution was the same as I was seeing with Ingo's suggestion of adding highlight links to my .vimrc. So this method probably works as well. But I found Ingo's method easier because I could do it in .vimrc, so I'll go for his answer and give this one an upvote. Thanks!